# Page "template" layout. HTML </head> header.php vs page.php

Tags: php, html

I've asked a similar question before, but I've got a more specific question about this "style" of creating a page.
I have 3 pages for a template, header.php, page.php and footer.php. I'm trying to allow myself to easily edit parts of the site within a single page, but also be able to have extra things in  on per-page basis. My current structure is:
header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Website Name<? if ($title) echo ' &ndash; ' . $title; ?></title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

page.php

```
<?
$title = 'Page Title';
require_once('includes/header.php');
?>
<!-- Any extra stuff for the header goes here -->
</head>
<body>
Page content goes here.
<? require_once('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

footer.php

```
<footer>
I am a footer
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Although this works, I cannot make a publicly editable header (menus etc) that easily since my header.php page does not contain anything in the `<body>`. However, closing the `<head>` in header.php would not allow me to add extra files (such a page-specific javascript) on per-page basis. To my knowledge, CSS and javascript being included within the `<body>` tag is not a good idea.
I'm guessing a further file (say, menu.php) would be required and included at the top of each page, after the `<head>` tag? However, that doesn't seem that easy to read/natural, I feel there must be a better solution?

Comment: Javascript should be included in the body tag, at the bottom of your page, unless it needs to execute before the loading (ie shiv in your exemple.)

Comment: @mdi Ah, I was aware that sometimes you should be put it in the body, which a second reason I posted that. Now I know which situation, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy solution is to have inside "header.php" a line to echo the content of $extraHeaders:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $extraHeaders ?>
...
```

Then, any page you want to add specific headers to (stylesheet, javascript file, etc.), you just include it in the $extraHeaders variable:

```
$extraHeaders = '<script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>'
```

And it will be automatically be included in the headers for that page.

---

To solve the problem of syntax highlighting and avoiding to have to escape the quotation marks, you can use the output buffer syntax:

```
ob_start();
?>
<your html goes here> Alternatively, you can include an html file here.
<?php
$extraHeaders = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
...
```

This will allow you to use a variable, as previously suggested, but with syntax highlighting, and there is no need to escape anything.

Comment: This is my current favourite method. It does remove syntax highlighting in Notepad++ (might be able to find a workaround?), and it does require that I use `"` or escape any `'` used, but that's workable.

Comment: @JosephDuffy There is a workaround using output buffers. See edit in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ob_start` + regex ( tags like `{title}` or `{scripts}` to have an access at the end of loading the "page".

Answer (score 0):

Make an `_autoload()` script to pre-load all those php files.

This way when ever there is anything new to put, you can always go tho the script containing the `_autoload()` function and update it there.

Btw, putting javascript at the very end of the `<body>` tag is actually a good practice.